# Ruby or PHP or Php Framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, php

I am starting a website and am wondering if I should go with PHP, a php framework, or ruby on rails? I want to make a website fast, easiest and without a big learning curve. I already know a little bit of php and a little ruby on rails...But which would be best?

OK so to clarify more on the topic of what my site will be, It's basically a Classified Ads website that needs to have a user login, ability to post classifieds, and categorizing, and basically anything else a classified website has.

Comment: It might help to provide a little bit more detail about the type of website you want to create.  Will it be mainly static content or will there be lots of user interaction and persistence that requires you to store information in a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put my vote in for Rails.  It's easy to get started building a website that requires persistence in a database, and there are many websites that host the framework.  I agree with @Squeegy that PHP is great for sprinkling dynamic content into an otherwise static page, but it sounds to me that you want something more involved, so I would go with Rails.

Comment: I think that as of know my number one choice is Rails...I've already designed a poor site with php, and havent really liked PHP. So I think I'll go with Rails. Thanks for your reccondmation!

Answer (score 2):

Start with anything you know better.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is great for sprinkling bits of dynamic content into a website.  Given your requirements "fast, easiest and without a big learning curve" I think PHP would be ideal.

Now a large and more complex site, that would be much better suited to a framework.  But with any framework also comes steep learning curve.

Comment: Large and complex site built by totally newbie... Do you believe it? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter.com, try it out, it rocks.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it once, but maybe I'll go back into it...